# What is the plot of the Star Wars Post-episode 6?

Tags: star-wars, books

Allowing for the fact that any film adaptation will have creative licence, could someone please provide an overview of the plot of Star Wars Episode 7, based on the books released since. Insofar as I'm aware (please correct me), there isn't a definitive 'Episode 7' book, with events taking place in the expanded universe. Are these post-episode 6 books considered canon?

Even if not, a paragraph summary of the next significant plot (as it is written in any book) post-episode 6 would be useful.

Comment: I didn't VTC, though I definitely thought about it. You should probably reword the question to be more about post-ROTJ stories than about the plot of EP7 specifically since it would all be pure speculation which falls outside the scope of this site.

Comment: Reworded as suggested.

Comment: This needs to be narrowed-down a bit more.  You're asking for a summary for dozens of books, comic books, etc.

Comment: So suggest an edit, don't close the question!

Comment: The "next significant plot" post-ROTJ does not really encompass dozens of books, comic books, etc. It's whatever comes next in the timeline.

Comment: @phantom42 Indeed, but the first paragraph waxes philosophical about tales that happen after Episode 6, of which there are *many*.  That part needs to be cleaned up before reopening the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No plot line has been revealed as of now. Lucas has his notes for what he intended to do, but has never confirmed anything.

JJ Abrams has only [just been announced as the next director](http://starwars.com/news/star-wars-is-being-kick-started-with-dynamite-jj-abrams-to-direct-star-wars-episode-vii.html) and neither he, Lucas, Lucasfilm/Disney or any of the producers have given any indication of what story they may or may not use, or if it will be an entirely new creation.

The non-[G-Canon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Canon) "[Expanded Universe](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Expanded_Universe)" books deal with the years after the Battle of Yavin, but again - there has been no indication that any of these stories will be used in any way.

That said...

As of now, the next chronological book would be [The Truce At Bakura](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Truce_at_Bakura), which Wikipedia summarizes as

> While recovering from their victory against the Empire at Endor, the Rebel Alliance intercepts an Imperial probe containing a distress call for the Emperor. The message details a lizardlike race of aliens invading the Outer Rim planet Bakura. With Palpatine dead and the Imperial Navy scattered, Luke Skywalker volunteers to lead a force to intercept the alien invasion and save Bakura.

It is, however, a single novel.

The next major story arc (i.e., trilogy), would be [The Heir To The Empire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heir_to_the_Empire) storyline. Wikipedia summarizes it as

> Heir to the Empire is part of the Star Wars Expanded Universe, and takes place five years after the events of Return of the Jedi. The Rebel Alliance has destroyed the Death Star, defeated Darth Vader and Emperor Palpatine, and driven out the remnants of the old Imperial Starfleet to a distant corner of the galaxy. Princess Leia and Han Solo are married and expecting twins. Luke Skywalker has become the first in a long-awaited new line of Jedi Knights.
>
> Thousands of light years away, Grand Admiral Thrawn, the last of the Emperor's Warlords, has taken command of the shattered Imperial Fleet, readied it for war, and pointed it at the fragile heart of the New Republic. Thrawn is searching for a Dark Jedi and is succeeding in restoring the Empire.

Officially, neither they, or any other existing story are more likely to be used as the source story for the new movie(s).

It should also be noted that the site run by [SuperShadow](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/SuperShadow) is a very old, *very* fake site. It pre-dates the prequels and all of his supposed inside-scoops were confirmed to be complete fabrications.

Comment: That's an excellent answer and just what I was looking for, thanks :)

Comment: They have stated that they aren't going to go with the Thrawn trilogy as most people had anticipated though.